# Exclude RecyclerView AdapterItem from being grouped as in the list by accessibility readers

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, talkback, accessibility

I have a screen which displays search results.  However there is always one item that is at the end of the list, which is not a search result, but a disclaimer.  When TalkBack is on, it counts this disclaimer as part of the list, which is confusing.

I have another screen, where search results are grouped into two categories based on their type, but displayed in the same `RecyclerView`.  It would be nice for the accessibility reader to consider them separate as well.

Is there a way to group certain adapter items into different accessibility lists within one `RecyclerView`/`Adapter`?

So if I have 10 total adapter items, but the bottom is the disclaimer, navigating to the first result in the list would announce:

```
Search result 1, select in list 9 items
```

Then, the discalimer at the end would be announced:

```
Disclaimer text, out of list
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the short answer is no.  Talkback reads the contents of widgets or the state of widgets and verbalizes the results.  It can not "interpret" the data or what each item in a RecyclerView is suppose to represent.  You are in control of what displays so why not just filter the last "Disclaimer" item so it is not included in the list?